# Multiplication in $L_p$

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $p\in [1,\infty)$. What is the norm of the map $T\colon L_p[0,1]\to L_p[0,1]$ given by

$Tf(x) = xf(x)$?

It is clear that $\|T\|\leqslant 1$.

Comment: You can find functions which cause that bound to be an equality. (:

Comment: Compute $\Vert T f\Vert/\Vert f\Vert$ for $f(x)=x^n$.

Answer (score 1):

More generally, the norm of multiplication by a function $\varphi$ on $L_p$ is equal to the essential supremum of $|\varphi|$, i.e., $\|\varphi\|_{\infty}$.

Indeed, for every $\epsilon>0$ the set $E = \{|\varphi|\ge \|\varphi\|_{\infty}-\epsilon\}$ has positive measure. Applying the operator to $\chi_E$ you will find that 
$$\|\varphi \chi_{E}\|_p \ge (\|\varphi\|_{\infty}-\epsilon) \|\chi_E\|_p$$
and the conclusion follows.